# STM32F407G-DISC1 AUX to Laptop Aux

Tags: stm32, signal-processing, microphone, sound

I am working with STM32F4 board and signal processing, generating some sin waveforms on CODEC, the problem is that I don't have oscilloscope on me and want to see what waveforms I am generating. I have found online mic analyzer (https://www.compadre.org/osp/pwa/soundanalyzer/) and would like to analyze my signal on it. I was hoping to connect one end of aux cord on dev board and other on my laptop, so dev board would work as output and laptop's aux as input, but windows does not recognize as any input device. Any way to use this set up on windows10?

Comment: While it is a good idea how to analyze generated waveforms, it's not an EE question why your web browser, running a javascript website, can't see and open your sound device in Windows 10.

Comment: I am sorry, I knew it might be wrong place to ask such question, but since I found out the answer, it might help others in signal processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that Reltek HD Audio Manager has a tab where I can select, whether the connected device is Mic or Headphones, selecting Mic will read the signal from my devboard. So  by doing this I managed to make a DIY oscilloscope for my uni assignments:
[image]